# Access content field from views in Orchard CMS 1.10.1

Tags: orchardcms

I would like to display certain first level menuitem in bold.
This setting should be done by a checkbox when the user create / edit a menu item. (I have a workaround using the `Model.Href`, but it is not nice).

So I created a boolean field in Content definition / *Menuitem URL* (I don't know the name of the corresponding content definition in English Orchard).

How to access a custom field (Content Field) from a view?
(There already is a view which is used to customize the menu)

The examples I found use custom shapes, where the fields are accessed as built in fields (e.g. `Model.ContentItem.FieldName` ). But this is a different case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of "Piedone", the solution:

```
Model.Content.ContentItem.MenuItem.FieldTechnicalName.Value
```

**Explanation**

Examining the *Model* object in Visual Studio, the *Model* is a dynamic shape that have eg. *Href* property and a *Content*.
*Content* is a *MenuPart*, that is a content part that have a *ContentItem* property with the content item itself. Technically only *content part*s have *Field*s. When you (seemingly) add a field to a type it will be a part corresponding the type's name, that is *MenuItem* in this case (It's confusing that the display name of '*MenuItem*' content type is *Custom Link*...)
The field's technical name is as you name it. When you add to a type, the *Value* will be a property of the *BooleanField* class. (By the way, it is nullable, so if you dont't save after adding the field, it will be null else the value you set).